# bx slider set number of images in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I want to set it so there's 3 text/images on the slider and it also works well with gallery with numbers not divisible by 3. If there's 5 images shows 3 in the first and 2 on the second.
I have a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/1/

Here's the javascript I'm using

```
// declare global
var slider_array = new Array();

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // launch bxslider
    $('.bxslider').each(function(i){
        slider_array[i] = $(this).bxSlider({controls:false, 
                                            });
    });


    // bind controls on custom controls, and run functions on every slider
    $('.bxslider-controls a').bind('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if($(this).hasClass('pull-left')) {
        $.each(slider_array, function(i,elem){
          elem.goToPrevSlide();  
        });

      } else if($(this).hasClass('pull-right')) {
        $.each(slider_array, function(i,elem){
          elem.goToNextSlide();  
        });
      }

    });

});
```

Comment: Please explain more. What is your expected result? Your code works fine with 5 images.

Comment: I want the slider to have 3 images on it displaying instead of the one so it slides 3 images at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have more than one slides in the viewport you have to specify a width in bxSlider options (for example 1/3 of the viewport), so bxSlider operates in carousel mode, and maximum number of slides that can be shown on the viewport. That makes bxSlider not very responsive, unless you update it via javascript (using reloadSlider method).

Look at Public Methods on http://bxslider.com/options for further reference

```
// declare global
var slider_array = new Array();

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  // launch bxslider
  $('.bxslider').each(function(i){
    slider_array[i] = $(this).bxSlider({controls:false, maxSlides:3, slideWidth:330 });
  });


  // bind controls on custom controls, and run functions on every slider
  $('.bxslider-controls a').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('pull-left')) {
      $.each(slider_array, function(i,elem){
        elem.goToPrevSlide();  
      });

    } else if($(this).hasClass('pull-right')) {
        $.each(slider_array, function(i,elem){
        elem.goToNextSlide();  
      });
    }

  });

});
```